# TCL:How to read each line of a file and split each column and save it as a variable

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to read a file one line a time, split its columns and saved it in variables. 
File looks like this:

```
%% cat Memory_minus.list
MEM_rf_2p_hce_1024x8_naxos1           RF           dual_port    1024  8 
MEM_rf_2p_hce_128x18_naxos1           RF           dual_port    128  18
MEM_rf_2p_hce_16x128_fusion           RF           dual_port    16   128 
MEM_rf_2p_hce_16x80_fusion4           RF           dual_port    16   80
MEM_rf_2p_hce_256x18_naxos1           RF           dual_port    256  18 
MEM_rf_2p_hce_256x8_naxos1            RF           dual_port    256  8
```

in a single foreach loop(one line) i wanted to have all 5 columns converted to variables, eg for first line each variable should return following.

```
puts $var1 ->>> MEM_rf_2p_hce_1024x8_naxos1
puts $var2 ->>> RF
puts $var3 ->>> dual_port
puts $var4 ->>> 1024
puts $var5 ->>> 8
```

I tried writing a code to read a file line by line and then extracting the items but it didn't worked.

```
set f [open Memory_minus.list]
while {1} {
    set line [gets $f]
    if {[eof $f]} {
        close $f
        break
    }
    #set base_name [exec awk {{print $1}} $line ]
    foreach lt $line {
        puts $lt
    }
}
```

$lt return whole scrambled outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set fp [open input.txt r]
while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
    # To make sure that the line has five words
    if {[llength $line]!=5} {
        puts "Incorrect format in the line -> '$line'"
        continue
    }
    foreach {var1 var2 var3 var4 var5} $line {
        puts ->>>$var1;puts ->>>$var2;puts ->>>$var3;puts ->>>$var4;puts ->>>$var5;
    }
}
close $fp
```

**Output :** (Showing only first line's output)

```
->>>MEM_rf_2p_hce_1024x8_naxos1
->>>RF
->>>dual_port
->>>1024
->>>8
```

Comment: You can put them into an array if you want to keep track of all those elements & give the variables with some meaningful name instead of var1, var2... etc.

Comment: I wanted to use these variables to do some post processing. Yeah they have a meaningful name. Thanks for the solution it works.

Comment: At the end of line i can still see "Incorrect format in the line -> ' ' getting printed. How to avoid that ?